# AWS IoT CLI - list-things returning empty list

Tags: aws-cli, aws-iot

I created a thing in the AWS IoT console, assigned certificate and policies. I tested `aws iot list-things` and I got:

```
{
    "things": []
}
```

But, as I told, there is a thing created. Same occurs with `list-certificates`. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting inconsistent results between using the CLI and what you see on the AWS web based interfaces, always double check :

- The AWS credential you are using for your CLI
- The default region configured for your CLI

Logout of your shell and login again, double check the above, and you should see the same results.

Remember that AWS Iot artifacts (things, certificates, policies, ...) are always created in a certain region.

Comment: You are right: I changed the region to us-east-2 instead of us-west-2 and it worked.

Comment: Do you know why the list of attributes comes empty: `{... "thingName": "SM1", 
            "attributes": {}
        }` ? When I created the thing SM1, at AWS IoT Console, I also created 3 attributes...